# multi-type List annotation translation: JAXB to SimpleXML

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd, simple-framework

i'm attempting to translate some JAXB xjc.exe generated classes to Simple XML classes.  i'm not sure how to annotate dynamic elements.  for example, in the schema, i have:

```
<!-- Message Set Request/Response Pairs and contained requests  -->
<xsd:element name="QBXMLMsgsRq">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xsd:element name="HostQueryRq" type="HostQueryRqType"/>
            <xsd:element name="CompanyQueryRq" type="CompanyQueryRqType"/>
            <xsd:element name="CompanyActivityQueryRq" type="CompanyActivityQueryRqType"/>
            <!-- many more of these choices -->
        </xsd:choice>
        <xsd:attribute name="oldMessageSetID" type="STRTYPE"/>
        <!-- some other attributes -->
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

which, when run through xjc.exe, generates the following annotation for the @XmlElement

```
@XmlElements({
    @XmlElement(name = "HostQueryRq", type = HostQueryRqType.class),
    @XmlElement(name = "CompanyQueryRq", type = CompanyQueryRqType.class),
    @XmlElement(name = "CompanyActivityQueryRq", type = CompanyActivityQueryRqType.class),
    //+ et al
})
protected List<Object> hostQueryRqOrCompanyQueryRqOrCompanyActivityQueryRq;
```

so how can i translate this JAXB structure to a SimpleXML annotated class structure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the answer is to use [ElementListUnion](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/ElementListUnion.html) to identify the available choices for the List types.  check [here](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/examples/examples.php) under "Collecting various types in a single list".  example:

```
@Root
public class Example {

   @ElementListUnion({
      @ElementList(entry="int", type=Integer.class, inline=true),
      @ElementList(entry="date", type=Date.class, inline=true),
      @ElementList(entry="text", type=String.class, inline=true)
   })
   private List<Object> list;
}
```